# I am making an app in android studios and i want a instagram function in it

Tags: java, android

In the instagram grid layout after we click on one of the image we go  to the scroll view and and the scroll view stops at the image we clicked on. Just tell me the approach if not code.please.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to do this.

The first one is to make a gridRecyclerView. The grid adapter will receive a list.

Then in the item on click listener create an intent to open a new Activity which will use the same list. Have a pointer to check which value is being clicked and navigate to it.
You can achieve this by using a intent.putExtra in your grid recycler view click listener.

.

Comment: Thank yous so much ,what should i use to navigate in the recycler view

Comment: put yout intent in the onBindView holder . And also intent.putExtra("position",position) to it.

Comment: yes i got that but when i go to the recycler view , what code should I use to navigate to the position we put in extras